# ClientAccessPolicy file download aborted

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, wcf, iis, clientaccesspolicy.xml

I have an ASP .NET 3.5 + Silverlight 3 web site hosted on Win Server 2003.

The url is of the following form:

```
https://test.website.com:31443
```

The Client Access Policy has been placed in the `inetpub/wwwroot` folder.

I have changed the TCP port to 31080 and SSL port to 31443 in the virtual directory properties (required by the client).

The client access policy has been verified and works for the default port 80 and 443, when a request is made to a Silverlight enabled WCF service from the Silverlight client.

However, after changing the ports (as above), Firebug shows `Aborted` when the clientaccesspolicy or crossdomain file is requested by Silverlight runtime.

The XAP download works fine and has the port appended to the URL.

But for the clientaccesspolicy file, the url does not have the port appended in the request.

To sum up the following **works**:

https://test.website.com:31443/clientaccesspolicy.xml

But the Silverlight runtime is trying to request the following which **does not work** and gets aborted:

https://test.website.com/clientaccesspolicy.xml

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the behavior you are seeing is by default. The Silverlight runtime will only request the clientaccesspolicy over HTTP to port 80, or TCP to 943. If the Silverlight application is run as a trusted app, I think you can get around these restrictions.

- [Blog Post](http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2010/03/20/silverlight-4-rc-socket-security-changes.aspx)
- [Issue on Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/616655/silverlight-4-wcf-net-tcp-client-cannot-read-the-client-access-policy-xml-file-using-tcp-on-port-943-instead-of-the-default-http-on-port-80)